# Possible to re-enable `uint` type in g++ 4.7+?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a mass of code that I'm trying to convert from g++ version 4.2.2 to 4.7.2.  In version 4.2.2 and prior, it seems that `uint` was defined as `unsigned int`.  I know this is not a standard c++ thing and that real men write ISO standard C++, but I was wondering if there was a flag or some sort of way to make g++ accept `uint` without modifying all the source files.  Can I change `CPPFLAGS` or add a switch to the g++ runline? My googles yielded nothing.  I have some source files coming from a different group at work and I'd like to accept their `uint` transgressions.

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    uint foo = 0xdeadbeef;
    cout<<hex<<foo<<endl;
}
```

yields:

```
/tmp/rbroger1/gcc_update rbroger1 @ plxc25804 
% /usr/intel/pkgs/gcc/4.2.2/bin/g++ ~/tmp.cc && ./a.out
deadbeef
/tmp/rbroger1/gcc_update rbroger1 @ plxc25804
% /usr/intel/pkgs/gcc/4.7.2/bin/g++ ~/tmp.cc && ./a.out
/nfs/pdx/home/rbroger1/tmp.cc: In function 'int main()':
/nfs/pdx/home/rbroger1/tmp.cc:8:5: error: 'uint' was not declared in this scope
/nfs/pdx/home/rbroger1/tmp.cc:8:10: error: expected ';' before 'foo'
/nfs/pdx/home/rbroger1/tmp.cc:9:16: error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Don't, but you could *#define* `uint` to be `unsigned int` by passing the appropriate flags to the compiler... That being said, it should be fairly simple to provide a `typedef` in a header that gets included, or better off, `grep` for the occurrences or `sed` edit them into `unsigned int`...

Comment: To expand on David Rodríguez's comment: Yes, you could use `-Duint="unsigned int"`, but it's icky! :-)

Comment: Well, gcc behavior changed.  That's why I'm wondering if someone knows how to tweak the behavior.

Comment: Yes, I've done the `typdef` thousands of times already on our repository.  I don't have permissions to a source file area.

Comment: @Ross: Exposing yourself to compiler changes is what happens when one relies upon nonstandard extensions. :) Don't think GCC is at fault here.

Comment: I'm not complaining.  I'm looking for a workaround.  I have source code that I need to compile from another group that is in an NFS area that I don't have permissions to change.  I've changed my own source code and many other files through out our repository.  My snide remark that "real men program in ISO c++" was an attempt to head-off a meta-discussion about whether using such a switch  was a good idea.  It seems that such a discussion can never be avoided here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `-include a_file_where_there_is_typedef_to_uint.h` flag to g++

[From the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)

> `-include file`
>
> Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the primary source file. However, the first directory searched for file is the preprocessor's working directory instead of the directory containing the main source file. If not found there, it is searched for in the remainder of the #include "..." search chain as normal.
>
> If multiple -include options are given, the files are included in the order they appear on the command line.